# Android-MysqlConnectivity in eclipse

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am new to android, So i need a basic knowledge,How to connect to the database and Select some of the values from it.

These are all the following steps i have already completed by watching and reading some online tutorials.

1. Created a New ANDROID Project Named **And2**.
2. Created a New JAVA Project named **MYSQLConnection** which is used to store the database connection.
3. I have Downloaded **mysql-connector-java-5.1.34** file Online and added it.
4. I have attached the Screen Shot[image: Eclipse] the total overview of my eclipse.

Now i just needed to access the database in **And2** and Write a Simple Select Query So that i can make sure that connection is created.

Shown below is the Java file for DB Connection.

```
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import com.mysql.jdbc.*;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;


 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


try
             {


    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase";
    String connectionUser = "root";
    String connectionPassword = "12345";


   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, 
   connectionPassword);
        //Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  //        ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from TableName");
    //       
  //        //Print the data to the console
   //       while(reset.next()){
     //     Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));
     //     
  //           } 
             }
catch ( SQLException err )
      {
    System.out.println("Database connection failed");

  }


  }
  }
```

Any Help appreciated.

Comment: localhost? You have installed MySQL database on your Android device? (:  You should write ip of your machine with MySQL.

Comment: If you are using an internal database, I suggest that you use SQLite. There are tons of tutorials about it. If it's a remote database running on another server it would be easier to add another "layer", like PHP or RESTful api which you use to retrieve data over HTTP.